# Reading email at regular intervals

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

What I am trying to do is write an app that logs into my email account and checks both Inbox and Sent items, at a regular period set by the user.

I have a few queries so I hope this isn't ignored due to it's length.

1. I think I need a `BroadcastReceiver` to start the `AlarmManager` after the phone has finished booting.
2. I need to do an `AsyncTask` to read the emails off the main UI thread. However, I read `Service`s also run on separate threads?
3. From the `PendingIntent` in the `AlarmManager` (why is this `PendingIntent` and not normal `Intent`?) Should I choose `getBroadcast()` or `getService()`?
4. My understanding of the whole process is:

   - phone finishes booting, fires broadcast
   - `BroadcastReceiver` gets event and sets `AlarmManager`
   - `AlarmManager` fires `Intent` at specific time
   - `BroadcastReceiver` gets event
   - `BroadcastReceiver` starts `Service`
   - `Service` starts `AsyncTask`

Is that right? It seems very long-winded. If I chose `getService()` instead of `getBroadcast()` as the `PendingIntent` could I skip calling the 2nd broadcast in the steps above, and go straight to the `Service`?

Re-reading this I guess I haven't asked specific questions, but I'm more interested to know if my understanding is correct or if I'm totally lost (I feel like I am!)

UPDATE: I think I'll use an intentservice they sound good as I can call them directly from the alarmmanager. However, reading around it appears that a service may not stay awake long enough so I may have to use a broadcast receiver anyway in order to use a wake lock, something I am now investigating further.

Commonsware has written a useful wrapper called WakefulIntentService which I think I'll use to help do my own wake lock stuff

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AlarmManager` to start a `Service` ([`getService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)). And a note that [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) runs on UI thread. So you *cannot* make network connections in a `Service` (to avoid of [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)). You need something like `Thread` in your `Service`, don't use `AsyncTask`, as [the document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says:

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Another choice is [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), it runs on a separate worker thread, you can do network jobs in there. Note that: *All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.*

Comment: It's interesting that the document says they're for short tasks as everywhere else I've read says they're for long tasks. I am going to use intentservice now anyway I think, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont have all the answers for you but I will tell you what I know:

3.`PendingIntent` is a waiting Intent and the difference is that this Intent intended to be sent in the future and not immediately as a regular intent would.

> service starts AsyncTask

Service doesn't need to start `AsyncTask`, you do one of those either you run a service in the background that will constantly run on a different thread. or you could use an `AsyncTask` that will create a thread, perform it's job and kill the thread at the end.

Comment: Where do I call the asynctask from though, if not in the service? From the broadcast receiver listening for the alarm?

Comment: you can call an AsyncTask from every location where you need to perform a potentially long task that could block your UI thread.